# Flexbox alignment issue in react-native

Tags: react-native, flexbox, expo

I'm trying to align the contents of a View component into left and right side of the screen. Unfortunately, whatever I do, I can only align the parent View and not the child View components.

In the snippet below,  ***item*** is the Parent View, ***leftIcon*** and ***title*** are supposed to be aligned together in the left and ***rightArrow*** is supposed to be aligned in the right.

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(`${item.page}`)}>
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.leftIcon}>a</Text>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.rightArrow}> > </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    //backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    paddingTop: 7,
    marginVertical: 4,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  leftIcon: {
    fontSize: 25,
    paddingRight: '5%',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 25,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
  rightArrow: {
    fontSize: 25,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end'
  }
});
```

[image: Image Settings Page]

This might be an incorrect approach, but what can be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `leftIcon` and `title` in a view with a `flexDirection: 'row'` style.
Then add `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to your `item` styles.

Example (using inline styles):

```
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View
            style={{
              marginVertical: 4,
              marginHorizontal: 16,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 25,
                  paddingRight: '5%',
                }}>
                a
              </Text>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>Title</Text>
            </View>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}> > </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: This indeed got me in the right direction and was able to solve the issue. Thank you so much!